# Cannot access to dockerized net 6 api

Tags: c#, .net, docker

My api project (my-custom-api) is using rabbitmq instance. Since both are running in docker I created custom docker network and run both containers on that same network.

```
docker create my-network

docker run -d --hostname my-rabbitmq --network my-network --rm -it -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3.11-management

docker run --network my-network --publish 8090:8080 -d my-custom-api
```

on docker ps -a both containers are up and running and inside docker log for my-custom-api there is no errors or warnings

However when I hit `localhost:8090/swagger/index.html` I'm getting This site can’t be reached. Using `curl localhost:8090` I'm getting `url: (52) Empty reply from server`

Here's the content of Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /App

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /App
COPY --from=build-env /App/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "My-Custom-Api.dll"]
```

Again, I'm not getting any errors in the docker log when trying to access localhost:8090 but still cannot access api from this address.

What I'm doing wrong here.

Update:
After I changed run command to include environment Development my container logs looks like this

```
2023-01-22 20:58:55 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2023-01-22 20:58:55       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
2023-01-22 20:58:55 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-01-22 20:58:55       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-01-22 20:58:55 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-01-22 20:58:55       Hosting environment: Development
2023-01-22 20:58:55 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-01-22 20:58:55       Content root path: /App/
2023-01-22 20:58:56 info: MassTransit[0]
2023-01-22 20:58:56       Bus started: rabbitmq://my-rabbitmq/
```

I still cannot open localhost:8090/ with or without swagger.

Comment: you haven't exposed the port in your docker file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger is not available by default when your program runs in a container.

In your Program.cs, you should see an if statement that makes it so Swagger is only available when your program runs in a development environment. A container is - by default - not considered development.

To run the program in development mode, you need to set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to 'Development'.

Another thing to be aware of is that the asp.net containers set the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS` to `http://+:80` making your app listen on port 80. So you need to map that, rather than port 8080.

You can see that your app is listening on port 80 in the log where it says `Now listening on: http://[::]:80`.

That means that you end up with a command like this:

```
docker run --network my-network --publish 8090:80 -d -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development my-custom-api
```

When you do that, Swagger will be available on port 8090.

Comment: It does make sense to get swagger in dev env with your suggestion in the run command. In the docker log I'm getting  'Hosting environment: Development' but still cannot open localhost:8090

Comment: @user1765862 Ah. I noticed that you mapped port 8080. It has to be port 80. I've updated my answer.